# Netlogo turtle stops being infectious after 14 days and starts after being infected

Tags: netlogo

ask turtles with [ infected? and ticks <= 14 ]
  [ 
    infect
  ]

this is my code, after a turtle becomes infected? he will also infect. but I want it to infect only in a 14 day period. what happens is that it infects only on the first 14 ticks and stop. What I want to do is for example, a turtle becomes infected in tick 5, then it will stop infecting in tick 19. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ticks` is the global time step counter so it increments from 0 (when you start the simulation with `reset-ticks`). What you are trying to do is have each turtle know when it became infected and then be infectious for the next 14 ticks. So you have to create a turtle variable that tracks when it becomes infected, and use that as the condition. Something like:

```
turtles-own
[ infected?
  when-infected
]

to infect
  ask turtles
  [ if < whatever code you have that exposes them >
    [ set infected? true                  ; you must have this already
      set when-infected ticks
    ]
  ...
end

to ???
  ask turtles with [ infected? and when-infected >= ticks - 14 ] [ infect ]
  ...
end
```

You can see that the replacement line compares the turtle's particular value of the new `when-infected` variable to the current value of `ticks`